# Android Recycled Bitmap Crash sent in via stacktrace report

Tags: android, canvas

I don't have a whole lot of information to go off of since the reports had no comments about what part of my game was being played when the crash occurred but from where I;m standing, it should be impossible to be getting this error.

This is the stackTrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap         
android.graphics.Bitmap@44d37950 at 
android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:955) at 
android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1044) at 
bladequest.graphics.DrawObject.render(DrawObject.java:81)
```

I get the error saying that recycled bitmaps are being used at some point in the program from lines 77 and from 81 (seperate stacktraces)

However, here is my code for those lines:

```
case Bmp1:
        if(bmp != null && !bmp.isRecycled())
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, f1, f2, p);
        break;
    case Bmp2:
        if(bmp != null && !bmp.isRecycled())
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, r1, r2, p);
        break;
```

How is it even possible that a recycled bitmap is ever making it to the draw call???

Comment: do you have the option to set bmp = null at some point when you're releasing it? Alternatively, you may want to manually collect garbage when you release it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason maybe the `onDraw` method has be invoked, if you want to recycle the bitmap, and avoid this error, suggestion override the `onDraw` method, in the ondraw, you need check the 
`bmp != null && !bmp.isRecycled()`

Comment: I tihnk the problem is that another thread is recycling the bitmap before it can be drawn.  basically the bitmap is put into an object which is placed into a drawqueue that draws to the screen concurrently with the game data....so in very rare cases the update thread is recycling the bitmap after it checks to see if it's recycled but before it's drawn......now how to fix that :(

Comment: if has more thread to operate this bitmap, you can define a volatile boolean var to check, for example:
`volatile boolean recycled = false;`
when you recycle, `recycled = true`,
when draw, check the recycled.

also, don't recycle in another thread, make the recycle in ui thread, you can send a recycle message to ui thread.

Comment: yeah I'm implementing a variation of that that should clear this mess up, thanks for the help :D